Limit Order Issues Dollar Cost Average Strat Pine Script
I am trying to turn an indicator into a strategy. I have made it to the step where I need to place limit orders so that I can use a dollar cost averaging method for risk management. It places the initial entry order properly. The take profit works properly for both the initial long entry and the DCA orders (when they do actually get placed.) The stop loss for the initial long entry works properly. However, trying to place limit orders with an if statement seems to only work when the strategy isn't in the initial long position. In addition, I can't really tell what weird behavior it is, but the dollar cost averaging orders labeled as DCA-1 and DCA-2 are behaving strangely in relation to the entryPrice. The dca orders almost seem to be using the correct entryPrice value, but just not executing until after the initial long position has closed (attaching example picture.) I was wondering if somebody could help identify why they are behaving strangely, and why I am not able to place the limit orders correctly?
Also, a pre-emptive question that I know I will have when I reach the next step, how do I go about modifying the take profit of open orders so that I can make them the average of the entry prices?
In the picture where I quickly drew lines showing the desired behavior, I forgot to add "stop loss" to the purple "Exit long" line. The last line will be the stop loss.
I apologize if there are more efficient ways to do what I am doing and it seems like it would be straightforward common sense. Please do include those potential solutions as I'm sure I'd have it wrong if that's the case.
//@version=5
strategy("Three Candle Fade", shorttitle = "3CF", pyramiding = 11, overlay=true, initial_capital = 100000, close_entries_rule = "ANY", calc_on_every_tick = true)


//Get user defined inputs
candles_counted = input.int(defval = 3, title = "Candles to Count", group = "Indicator Settings")
grid_no = input.int(defval = 3, title = "Number of Grids", group = "Trading Settings")
perc_risk = input.int(defval = 1, title = "Percent of Risk", group = "Trading Settings")
pos_size = input.float(defval = 400000, title = "Position Size", group = "Trading Settings")
grid_spacing = input.float(defval = 250.00, title = "Grid Spacing", group = "Trading Settings", tooltip = "The spacing between grids in ticks (10 ticks = 1 pip)")
stpticks = input.int(defval = 250, title = "Take Profit (Short)", group = "TP/SL")
ltpticks = input.int(defval = 250, title = "Take Profit (Long)", group = "TP/SL")

//initialize variables for strategy
var float entryPrice = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)
var float initialEntryPrice = 0.00
var float gsfl = grid_spacing * 0.00001
ll1 = entryPrice - gsfl
ll2 = entryPrice - (gsfl * 2)
longStop = entryPrice - (gsfl * grid_no)

//initialize variables for indicator
var float storedvalue = 0.00
var int candle_count_bull = 0
var int candle_count_bear = 0
var bool isCountingBull = true
var bool isCountingBear = true
var int ccthree = 0

//condition for entering positions
longCondition = candle_count_bear == candles_counted
shortCondition = candle_count_bull == candles_counted

//reset candle counts after they reach input number
if(candle_count_bull >= candles_counted)
    ccthree := ccthree+1

if(candle_count_bear >= candles_counted)
    ccthree := ccthree+1

if(ccthree >= 1)
    candle_count_bear := 0
    candle_count_bull := 0
    ccthree := 0

if(isCountingBull == true)
    if(high > storedvalue and close < storedvalue)
        storedvalue := high
        isCountingBull := true
        isCountingBear := false
    else if(high > storedvalue and close > storedvalue)
        storedvalue := high
        isCountingBull := true
        isCountingBear := false
        candle_count_bull := candle_count_bull+1
    else if(high <= storedvalue or close <= storedvalue)
        storedvalue := storedvalue
        candle_count_bull := 0
        isCountingBull := false
        isCountingBear := true

if(candle_count_bull > candles_counted)
    candle_count_bull := candles_counted


if(isCountingBear == true)
    if(low < storedvalue and close > storedvalue)
        storedvalue := low
        isCountingBear := true
        isCountingBull := false
    else if(low < storedvalue and close < storedvalue)
        storedvalue := low
        isCountingBear := true
        isCountingBull := false
        candle_count_bear := candle_count_bear+1
    else if(low >= storedvalue or close >= storedvalue)
        storedvalue := storedvalue
        candle_count_bear := 0
        isCountingBear := false
        isCountingBull := true

if(candle_count_bear > candles_counted)
    candle_count_bear := candles_counted

if(strategy.position_size != 0)
    entryPrice := strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)
//Enter positions when candle count input is met
if(strategy.position_size == 0)
//    if(grid_no == 1)
//        strategy.entry("Enter Long", direction = strategy.long, qty = pos_size)
//        entryPrice := strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)
//        strategy.exit("Exit Long", from_entry = "Enter Long", profit = ltpticks, loss = 250)

//    if(grid_no == 2)
//        strategy.entry("Enter Long", direction = strategy.long, qty = pos_size)
//        strategy.exit("Exit Long", from_entry = "Enter Long", profit = ltpticks, loss = entryPrice - (250 * 2))
//        strategy.entry("DCA-1", direction = strategy.long, limit = longLimit1, qty = pos_size)
//        strategy.exit("Exit DCA-1", from_entry = "DCA-1", profit = ltpticks, loss = entryPrice - 250)
        
    if(grid_no == 3 and longCondition)
        strategy.entry(id = "Enter Long", direction = strategy.long, qty = pos_size)
        strategy.exit("Exit Long", from_entry = "Enter Long", stop = longStop, profit = ltpticks)
        entryPrice := strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)
    if(close < entryPrice - gsfl and grid_no == 3)
        strategy.entry(id = "DCA-1", direction = strategy.long, qty = pos_size)
        strategy.exit("Exit DCA-1", from_entry = "DCA-1", stop = longStop, profit = ltpticks)
    if(close < entryPrice - (gsfl * 2) and grid_no == 3)
        strategy.entry(id = "DCA-2", direction = strategy.long, qty = pos_size)
        strategy.exit("Exit DCA-2", from_entry = "DCA-2", stop = longStop, profit = ltpticks)



]


I fixed this by removing the if(strategy.position_size == 0) from the global scope and adding it to the if statement for the first order to be placed.
